# Edittext auto fill overlay of activity is visible over fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, autofill, android-autofill-manager

I'm facing issue with auto-fill functionality,

If an auto-fill overlay is visible in activity and if i open a fragment then the auto-fill overlay is visible over fragment as well.

If i have an email field in activity and also in fragment, and if i auto fill email in fragment, email field in activity is also updated with auto fill value.

**minSdk - 21,
tagetSdk - 28**

Comment: Are you using Autofill service supported from API >= 26 ? And looked at android:importantForAutofill="yesExcludeDescendants"

Comment: Yes, but what about sdk < 26 ?

Comment: Just noticed the minSdk set to 21